# How to deploy Magento code to one host in a cluster

Tags: magento-1.8

We run a Magento 1 CE cluster where we have split the frontend and admin away to separate clusters. This gives us the ability to deploy schema changes to the admin host first, which is great, but it also introduces a problem.

When we deploy modules to the admin host, we typically leave all caches on except layout cache. With our last deploy our admin broke, because it threw an error on a missing helper class.

The reason for this is probably, that the fronts (admin and fonts share the same cache prefix id) did not have that module, and the admin picked up on that cache?

How could we prevent this in future? 
Would it help to disable all caches when we deploy?

Comment: how do you expect to deploy code to admin and not to frontend??

Comment: simple. they are on different servers, as I've mentioned above

Comment: right, but admin and frontend are the same codebase and database - you have to keep them in sync all time... so you need to flush cache also

Answer (score 0):

Because of our setup, we have a different cluster for the Magento Admin, and the Magento Frontend (customer facing)

Because of this we have the ability to deploy a different /app/etc/local.xml to the fronts, and the admins. 
In the fronts we added

```
<config>
  <global>
    <skip_process_modules_updates>true</skip_process_modules_updates>
    ..
  </global>
<config>
```

This gives us the confidence that the fronts will no longer initiate module / schema updates

Now we have the freedom to deploy all the code, at once, to the fronts and the admins

We also disable cache before we deploy